# How to make ticks of a colorbar in a MATLAB figure bold along with LaTeX interpreter?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to make ticks of a colorbar in a MATLAB figure bold along with LaTeX interpreter. I've tried this,

```
colorbar('TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex', 'Fontweight', 'bold');
```

It becomes LaTeX but not bold.

Comment: For LaTex, you need to use the LaTex markup. As far as I know '/textbf' is the markup for bold text.

Comment: The ticks or the tick labels?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ticks.

Comment: There is no property to affect ticks by themselves, but you can set the `'LineWidth '` property of the axes, which will affect the axes and ticks. So increasing that value will make your ticks thicker. The alternative is to manually draw thicker lines on top of the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you'll need to use latex tags to edit all your labels. This can be done with:

```
cb = colorbar('TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex');
cb.TickLabels = strcat('\textbf{', cb.TickLabels, '}');
```

The second line adds the markup `\textbf` before each tick label and encloses it with `{}`, so the outcome is:

```
>> cb.TickLabels
ans =
  11×1 cell array
    '\textbf{0}'
    '\textbf{0.1}'
    '\textbf{0.2}'
    '\textbf{0.3}'
    '\textbf{0.4}'
    '\textbf{0.5}'
    '\textbf{0.6}'
    '\textbf{0.7}'
    '\textbf{0.8}'
    '\textbf{0.9}'
    '\textbf{1}'
```

which interpreted as bold text if you change the interpreter to 'latex'.

Note, that the markup `\mathbf` does not work.